# What is the status of the divorce if it were given through court stamp paper according to Shia Islamic law?

Tags: sharia, shiism, talaq

My marriage broke up in 2007 after my wife was caught cheating. She was taken away at her own request by her family and I have not seen, heard, talked or have had any other contact with her or her family, whatsoever since that time. My children are all married and independent. I formally sent her a divorce deed in 2010 on a stamp court paper duly witnessed and notarized.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this divorce deed valid?
2. What is the status of this marriage when both partners have had no contact for 6 years?
3. Do I now have to get a divorce again as per the Shia Islamic law?

Answer (score 2):

Your divorce is acceptable by law, but if you have not said the Arabic divorcing statement, this divorce is not acceptable by religion. As you are a man you have a right to divorce your wife by Arabic statement and with paying her your duties. If you have done all of above things, your divorce is OK.

Comment: "acceptable by law". Well it depends on the country in which the husband and the wife is.